# How to select "column" in nested list?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, replace, nested, selection

Lets say I have a nested array like this:

```
 
   [
    ['2020-06-17 00:10:00'  2345    145   27245 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:11:00'  8999    189   28999 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:12:00'  8492    192   28492 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:13:00'  1233    134   29334 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:14:00'  3352    135   28234 ]
                                                 ]
```

How can I select a specific "Column" from that if:

A) its a list of lists

B) its an numpy array of numpy arrays

and set it replace it by the values of a 1d list/ array of the same length, for example [ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

C) Plus how can I drop one specific column?

Answer (score 3):

A) You can do this by doing the following. Note I have stored this in variable alist and it is not the same array as shown.

```
alist = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
 [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
 [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]]
```

If you wanted to get, say the 3rd column, this is the code(note: zero-indexing applies):

```
[row[2] for row in alist]
```

B) For NumPy, it is even easier. We have the same list turned into an array, but now, we just specify the parameters to get the 3rd column.

```
import numpy as np
npalist = np.array(alist)
npalist[:,2]
```

Basically, I just imported numpy, converted the 2d list into a 2d numpy array. Then I entered the parameters. If there is a colon in the first parameter, then there are all rows. If there is a colon in the second parameter, then there are all columns. We specified a specific column(i.e the 3rd column), and you can run this code on your local file system.

We can replace the third column with array [100,200,300,400] by doing this:

```
npalist[:,2] = [100,200,300,400]
```

Even though it is not the same shape as your array, it is the same logic.

C) For the third question, I will be performing it on NumPy. We can use the np.delete() function(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html).
As you could see, we need to input 3 parameters; the array; the row or column number, and the axis. You will see what I mean later on. If we want to drop the third column, we can run the following code.

```
np.delete(npalist, 3, 1)
```

If you don't know what that means, well here it is. The first parameter is obviously, the array name. The second parameter is the row or column number. So if we want the 3rd row, we type in 2(zero-indexing). If we want the 3rd column, we still type in 2. What's the catch?

It's the last parameter. If it is 0, then we are dropping rows. If it is 1, then we are dropping columns. As you can see the above code snippet uses axis 1 as we are dropping columns.